# classic username/password login in oauth1 native client flows

Tags: android, ios, api, oauth

I'm working on a web project that'll have an api for mobile native clients ( Android & iPhone). I've read lots of documents. Since I don't want to use SSL/TLS, I decided to use OAuth 1 based on the ex-lead author's of OAuth critiques about OAuth 2.0.

My question is the following;

I have a database function namely; `function login( email,password)` that gives error in invalid user credentials. I can't understand exactly where I should use this function.

is `function login( email, password)` function one of the api calls after getting all the `access_token` and `access_token_secret` ?

or

is `function login( email, password)` one of the intermediary step that should be used in getting request token, getting `oauth_token` & `oauth_token_secret` ?